# argparse default option based on another option

Tags: python, default, argparse

Suppose I have an argparse python script:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
parser.add_argument("--foo", required=True)
```

Now I want to add another option --bar, which would default to appending "_BAR" to whatever was specified by --foo argument.

My goal:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO'])
>>> Namespace(foo='FOO', bar="FOO_BAR")
```

AND

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO', '--bar', 'BAR'])
>>> Namespace(foo='FOO', bar="BAR")
```

I need something like this:

```py
parser.add_argument("--bar", default=get_optional_foo + "_BAR")
```

Comment: hmm, how could argparse implement this natively? Perhaps pass a tuple of the names of the arguments you want passed to the function, and a function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's another attempt at writing a custom Action class

```py
import argparse
class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    # adapted from documentation
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
        defaultbar = getattr(namespace, 'bar')
        try:
            defaultbar = defaultbar%values
        except TypeError:
            # BAR has already been replaced
            pass
        setattr(namespace, 'bar', defaultbar)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--foo", required=True, action=FooAction)
parser.add_argument("--bar", default="%s_BAR")

args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'Foo', '--bar', 'Bar'])
# Namespace(bar='Bar', foo='Foo')
args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'Foo'])
# Namespace(bar='Foo_BAR', foo='Foo')
args = parser.parse_args(['--bar', 'Bar', '--foo', 'Foo'])
# Namespace(bar='Bar', foo='Foo')
```

Note that the class has to know the `dest` of the `--bar` argument.  Also I use a `'%s_BAR'` to readily distinguish between a default value, and a non default one.  This handles the case where `--bar` appears before `--foo`.

Things that complicate this approach are:

- default values are evaluated at `add_argument` time.
- default values are placed in the Namespace at the start of `parse_args`.
- flagged (optionals) arguments can occur in any order
- the `Action` class is not designed to handle interacting arguments.
- the `bar` action will not be called in the default case.
- the `bar` default could be a function, but something would have to check after `parse_args` whether it needs to be evaluated or not.

While this custom Action does the trick, I still think the `addbar` function in my other answer is a cleaner solution.

Comment: I tried this, but `__call__` was never called

Comment: @AT, an `Action` is called if the user provides a value, which would be always be the case if `required`.  It is not called when just returning the default.

Answer (score 31):

I would, as a first try, get this working using an after-argparse function.

```
def addbar(args):
    if args.bar is None:
        args.bar = args.foo+'_BAR'
```

If this action needs to be reflected in the `help`, put it there yourself.

In theory you could write a custom `Action` for `foo` that would set the value of the `bar` value as well.  But that requires more familiarity with the `Action` class.

I tried a custom `Action` that tweaks the `default` of the `bar` action, but that is tricky.  `parse_args` uses the defaults right at the start, before it has acted on any of the arguments.

Comment: I would like to know why this was down voted.  No one else has suggested a solution, much less a better one.

Comment: Dunno, but +1 from me. I like the simplicity of this solution better than a custom Action, though an ArgumentParser subclass that added dependencies between arguments would be pretty cool.